# What is the difference between Object, Object and [1: Object, 2: Object]?

Tags: javascript

I just stumbled upon this while deleting an object in an array.

Here is the code:

```
friends = [];

friends.push(
    {
        a: 'Nexus',
        b: 'Muffin'
    },
    {
        a: 'Turkey',
        b: 'MonkMyster'
    }
    )

console.log(friends);

for(i in friends){
    if(friends[i].a == 'Nexus'){
          delete friends[i];
        friends.push({
            a: 'test',
            b: 'data'
        });
    }
}

console.log(friends);
```

It is posted on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t4rcLrgf/) as well.

Basically, why does my first `console.log` of `friends` output:
`[Object, Object]`

But, when deleting that object in the loop and then adding a new object to the array, it logs:

`[1: Object, 2: Object]`

What exactly does `1:, 2:` mean (obviously to associate for each object), but I wonder why it's not there after the first logging of `friends`? Is my object notation in my friends array wrong? I feel like I'm creating the initial `friends` array wrong and the JavaScript parser is correcting me?

Comment: It's not really a good idea to use `for ... in` loops to iterate through arrays.

Comment: @Pointy Would it be better to do `for(i=0; i < friends.length; i++){}` than for in on the object inside?

Comment: You should use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove items from Array

Comment: @NiCkNewman yes, or use the Array prototype iteration functions (`.forEach()`, `.map()`, etc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you deleted the first item (without reindexing) and pushed a new one.

Initially, you had an array with an object at its 0th position, and another one at the 1st one.

After the change, you have an array with an object at the 1st position, and another one at the 2nd one.

Therefore, the console just wants to show that the first entry is at the 1st position instead of at 0th one.

Each console may do this differently, for example on Firefox I get

```
Array [ <1 empty slot>, Object, Object ]
```

The console is just a debugging tool, you can just ignore those syntaxes. You are not doing anything wrong.

However, using sparse arrays may be a bit odd. You can consider reindexing the array instead of just deleting the property:

```js
delete array[position];    // Just remove
array.splice(position, 1); // Remove and reindex
```

Comment: Yep, that's the reason. Additionally, if your original array was three or more elements long, and you deleted friends[1] you'd get something like this `[Object, 2: Object, 3:Object]`. It is just a way to show which modifications have been done

Comment: `"Therefore, the console just wants to show that the first entry is at the 1st position instead of at 0th one."` Bingo. I will definitely do the splice method now since I'm dealing with an array and not objects (Well, objects in an array lol).  Don't know why Josh's answer is gone but his helped me too ~ [Offtopic, but if you do this same delete an object in array approach in nodejs it leaves a small comma behind, I find that funny lol] [look](http://i.gyazo.com/46d286aeca1b90cf3f2f4207ff299568.png)  It's telling me to switch to the splice method! :P

Comment: When manipulating array length, keep in mind that you will lose your place in the array if you're going up. If you had two items that should be deleted in a row for example, it will miss the second. An easy way to get around this is going through the array backwards `for(i=friends.length-1; i >=0; i--)`. Another option, since you're pushing a new object into the array, is to do it at the position you're at `friends[i] = { myProp:"myString" };`, then you'll be overwriting the old object anyways.

Comment: @Oriol it's fine to do a for in on my type of array right? I used the forEach method and it console logged the same keys, and same results, seems like the same exact loop. (It didn't console log anything more or less than forEach did), or when doing a regular for loop, than for inning the object... (I know for in is a sin and only supposed to be for objects), but I havn't seen an issue and it's so much faster to write lol. What's your take on it for my specific example?

Comment: @NiCkNewman A `for...in` loop will iterate non-integral properties, will iterate enumerable inherited properties, will skip missing integral properties (if the array is sparse) and may iterate the properties in any order. So `for...in` loops are not wrong, but use them with care.